# Power BI - Issue identifying two similar columns

Tags: visualization, powerbi

I have two imported tables that both have a "Description" column with the same values as entries. I create a measure in the one table to give me an average value per description area and when I display it, it works. However, if I try to display this average using the description column from the other table, it just give a single value for all description. Why does it do this, and not recognize that the description columns are similar?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to create a relationship between the two columns.

Comment: Hi, thank you, and I need to have a table with unique description values for that :)

Comment: Please include a minimal repro for your scenario, e.g. with some example CSV data to highlight the problem.